# I'd like to make my src path with an external ID combined by <select>tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<div id="select box" align="center">

    <select class="combine" id="yy" name="Year">
      <option value="16">2016</option>
      <option value="15">2015</option>
      <option value="14">2014</option>
      <option value="13">2013</option>
      <option value="12">2012</option>
    </select>

    <select class="combine" id="ff" name="Field">
      <option value="IR">IR 국제정치학</option>
      <option value="IL">IL 국제법</option>
      <option value="WTO">WTO 국제경제법</option>
      <option value="IG1">IG1 통합논술I</option>
      <option value="IG2">IG2 통합논술II</option>
    </select>

    <select class="combine" id="pp" name="PB#">
      <option value="first">제1문</option>
      <option value="second">제2문</option>
      <option value="thrid">제3문</option>
      <option value="fourth">제4문</option>
    </select>
</div>

<div align= "center">
<input type="text" id="IDF" name="slot_identifier" value="" />
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
     $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.combine').on('change', function(){
            var slot_identifier = $('#yy').val() + '_' + $('#ff').val() + '_' + $('#pp').val();
            $('#IDF').val(slot_identifier);
        });
    });
</script>
```

Above is my tag.
I have three select tags and I make it come out with a result which is assigned to the "slot_identifier". 
I'd to pass it to the src path to embed the pdf file. such as below.

```
<iframe id="iframepdf" src="slot_identifier.pdf"></iframe>
```

I have several pdf files such as "16_IR_first.pdf" in the same folder with index.html.

how could I pass the above combined slot_identifier to the src name?
please help me.

Answer (score 0):

```
// under
$('#IDF').val(slot_identifier);

// add this
$('#iframepdf').attr('src', slot_identifier + '.pdf');
```